# Method not override in java script prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I just reading `java script prototype programming`, just tried one small code.

```
function Ninja(){
  this.swingSword = function(){
    return true;
  };
}

//override the prev one
Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function(){
  return false;
};

var ninja = new Ninja();
console(ninja.swingSword());
```

but I thought the OP of this will be `false`, unfortunately it has given output as `true`, my second method is not overriding first one. why?

only `Ninja.prototype.swingSword()` [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1cywu9s/) this give correct override .....

So what is the purpose creating `object(ninja)` here ?

Comment: If exists object's own properties override the ones with the same name at the prototype. The point is you will keep the private object properties within the object and move the properties and methods those can be shared among the created objects to the prototype..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a function on a prototype extends that function to all its instances.

When you call the function it will always look at the instance itself first. If it doesn't find the function on the instance, then it looks at the prototype.

Since you are essentially overriding the prototype `swingSword` by creating a `swingSword` function directly in your Ninja constructor, which ensures that every instance of `Ninja` will already have a `swingSword` function, it never bothers looking for it on the prototype.

Answer (score 4):

You have two `swingSword` functions.

One is on the prototype. The other is on the instance (and assigned by the constructor function).

When you try to access the `swingSword` property, JS first looks on the object, then (if it doesn't find it) it looks up the prototype chain.

So it finds the one defined by the constructor function first, then it stops looking.

In short: The override works in the opposite direction to what you appear to be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you query the property x in the object o.

If o does not have an own property with that name, the prototype object of o is queried for the property x. If the prototype object does not have an own property by that name, but has a prototype itself, the query is performed on the prototype of the prototype. This continues until the property x is found or until an object with a null prototype is searched.

As you can see, the prototype attribute of an object creates a chain or linked list from which properties are inherited.

And same is the case with this problem. Your object has own function so it never looks it in prototype object and you always get the result returned by the object's own swingSword() function...